# PHP Convert Image/PDF Link To File

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am working with specific API and I need to pass a file(image/pdf) to API as following way.

`$file =  new CURLFILE('/Users/my-name/Downloads/500-536x354.jpeg')`

But I have file(image) as a Web URl like `https://example.com/image.png`

How can I pass `https://example.com/image.png` as same as new CURLFILE('/Users/my-name/Downloads/500-536x354.jpeg')`?

I just tried to pass this as like `$file =  new CURLFILE('https://example.com/image.png')`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Download the file to your site first (e.g. file_put_contents) and **then** use the CURLFILE class

Comment: pls add more info. The server that is receiving the $file, what do they do with it? is it like a simple form file attachment? something else?

Comment: Thanks@KenLee After Appling your suggestion  it  It works fine, please add this as a answer, I will accept it.